# Is there an equivalent of Chrome's DevTools' Sources panel in Firefox DevTools?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

In the below image, as you can see, there is a *Sources* tab that allows me to browse through my project files.

[image: *Sources* tab in Chrome DevTools]

[image: Sources shown in Chrome DevTools]

Also, my Firefox DevTools do not show a *Storage* tab. I believe that is the tab that will allow me to browse my project files. How do I enable it?

[image: Sources shown in Firefox DevTools]

This is my actual project structure:

[image: Project structure in file system]

Comment: "Network" → "Response" → "Raw"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Firefox DevTools don't have a panel that shows all files at one place the way the Chrome DevTools do it. Though there are different specialized panels showing you the same info. E.g. the [*Style Editor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Style_Editor) shows you all CSS sources. The [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) shows all requested files with focus on network request information.

The *Debugger* is meant to debug JavaScript. So, it only displays JavaScript sources.

The *Storage* panel is enabled by default in newer versions of the Firefox DevTools. To enable the *Storage* panel in older versions of Firefox you need to switch to the settings and click the checkbox besides *Storage*:

[image: Storage panel activation]

Though the purpose of the *Storage* panel is to display storages like cookies, the IndexedDB, the local and session storage. It does not display files.

Comment: What about `html` files. My purpose is to debug a `javascript` code in my html file.

Comment: JavaScript code in HTML files is also displayed within the *Debugger* panel. Generally, all JavaScript code is available in there. You can also [debug dynamically generated JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Debug_eval_sources) (e.g. created via `eval()` or by appending a `<script>` tag to your DOM via JavaScript) there.

Comment: Information around images is shown within the *Inspector* and the *Network* panels.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not have the same devtools setup as chrome, however it does have an editor that runs javascript in the console section. Click on the drop down icon with the blue notification (far right)
.... see pics

[console icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo5wl.png)

[console icon opens this editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFNbi.png)